# Comparing two tables in MS-Access and find / show only differences

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables in MS Access, one table with current active clients, and one table with overall clientele. I need to compare the two and find which clients in the overall client table are not active. The two tables have very similar structures(SSN, Fname,Lname,address,zip code etc).

I tried solving this by using the "find unmatched query wizard" in Access, using the SSN as the field to relate the tables. However, it ends up spitting out the entirety of the table back at me, with no filtration.

Here is the code when I switch to the SQL view of what I have tried from the wizard :

```
SELECT [Client Table].[Client Last Name], [Client Table].[Client FirstName], 
[Client Table].SSN, [Client Table].[Address Street Name]

FROM [Client Table] LEFT JOIN [Active Client List] ON [Client Table].[SSN]
= [Active Client List].[SS#]

WHERE ((([Active Client List].[SS#]) Is Null));
```

I was hoping to find the clients in my main client table, that do not have any records within the active client list table, but the query returns ALL clients from my main client table, with no filtered results.

Comment: Your query should be doing what you want.

Comment: Why do you have two tables to begin with? Have one clients table with a field to flag 'inactive'. Query works for me.

Comment: That would've been the better solution, but I was inherited the other table and needed to compare for some irl context.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid the () around in where condition

```
    SELECT [Client Table].[Client Last Name]
            , [Client Table].[Client FirstName]
            , [Client Table].SSN
            , [Client Table].[Address Street Name]

    FROM [Client Table] 
    LEFT JOIN [Active Client List] ON [Client Table].[SSN] = [Active Client List].[SS#]

    WHERE [Active Client List].[SS#]  Is Null;
```

Comment: Parens were not an issue for me. Access adds them automatically.

Comment: Yeah I removed the parens,made no difference in my output. However when I tried to filter by another variable(first name for ex) it does filter the results, so I feel maybe it's a problem with how the table is structured?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  .. your actula result , your expected  result and the working query too ..